# How to pair two items from different arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, random

Let's assume that I have two arrays with objects in them.

```
 var teams = [tobj1, tobj2 ...]
 var players = [pobj1, pobj2 ...]
```

The objects have 1 property (name: teamname/playername).

```
var tobj1 = {
name: playername // this comes from an inputfield
}
```

What I'm trying to do is pairing randomly a team with a player until every team got a player. The number of teams are equal to the number of players.

*Hint: it will be a football draw app*

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let players = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];
const teams = [ { name: '1' }, { name: '2' }, { name: '3' } ];

const appairedTeams = teams.map( team => {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);

  team.player = players[index];

  players.splice(index, 1);

  return team;
});
```

Or if you don't want to create a new object:

```
let players = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];
let teams = [ { name: '1' }, { name: '2' }, { name: '3' } ];

teams.forEach( team => {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);

  team.player = players[index];

  players.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Or if you want the player's name only:

```
let players = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];
let teams = [ { name: '1' }, { name: '2' }, { name: '3' } ];

teams.forEach( team => {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);

  team.playerName = players[index].name;

  players.splice(index, 1);
});
```